# SQL update with sub-query takes too long to run

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, subquery

I have a SQL update query that runs with my test data, but doesn't complete (2 hours or more) with my production data.

**The purpose of the query**

I have an ADDRESSES table that uses code strings instead of IDs. So for example ADDRESSES.COUNTRY_CODE = "USA" instead of 3152. For referential integrity, I am changing these code strings to code IDs.

**Schema**

ADDRESSES (~356,000 records)

- ADDR_ID (PK)
- COUNTRY_CODE (varchar)
- Address line 1 (varchar)
- etc.

COUNTRY_CODES

- CODE_ID (PK)
- CODE_STRING (varchar)
- etc.

**Steps**

First, I create a temporary table to store the address records with the appropriate code ID:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_TEMP
AS
   SELECT ADDR_ID, CODE_ID
     FROM    ADDRESSES
          LEFT JOIN
             COUNTRY_CODES
          ON ADDRESSES.COUNTRY_CODE = CODE_STRING
```

Second, I null the COUNTRY_CODE column and change its type to NUMBER.

Third I set the COUNTRY_CODE column to the code IDs:

```
UPDATE ADDRESSES
   SET COUNTRY_CODE =
          (SELECT ADDRESS_TEMP.CODE_ID
             FROM ADDRESS_TEMP
            WHERE ADDRESS_TEMP.ADDR_ID = ADDRESSES.ADDR_ID)
```

It is this third step that is taking hours to complete (2 hours and counting). The ADDRESSES table has ~356,000 records. There is no error; it is still running.

**Question**

Why isn't this update query completing? Is it dramatically inefficient? I think I can see how the sub-query might be an N<sup>2</sup> algorithm, but I'm  inexperienced with SQL.

Comment: I would think that the update query would effect every row in your table as this has no where clause.  Have you tried running SQL Profiler to see what is actually being passed to your database?

Comment: I see what you mean, @SimonPrice, but this query does complete successfully with the expected results with a much smaller data set. I'm not entirely sure how the update-set-subquery works (I wrote this query some months ago), so I will revisit the documentation to refresh my memory.

Comment: Try adding an index to ADDRESS_TEMP On the ADDR_ID column.

Comment: if it is completing with a much smaller data set, how big is the data set youre working with that doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess on the Oracle Optimizer internals: 'ADDRESS_TEMP' has no Primary Key nor any index on addr_id. Therefore the update really takes an n^2 approach. It basically scans thru the temp table for every row in the addresses table.

So, recommendation: make addr_id the Primary Key of the temp table.

If this does not help give us the execution tree that the Oracle optimizer produces. This will give more clarity in what actually happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Aftering making ADDRESS_TEMP.ADDR_ID a primary key, the query took 3.5 minutes to run. This is my first real-life experience with the importance of indices -- it's eye-opening.

Comment: @DavidS I'm surprised that the query would not use a hash join between addresses and address_temp, and wonder if there were no statistics on the address_temp table and that skewed the execution plan. An update based on a hash join should be faster than one based on nested loops where all rows are joined. You'd have to look at the explain plan before and after to be sure, but please don't learn from this that "indexes = good, full table scans = bad" -- it is a gross simplification, particularly for bulk data manipulation of this type.

Comment: Most of that went over my head, @DavidAldridge, because I only know basic SQL, but I appreciate you warning me against jumping to conclusions.